# Changing Customizer Select To Checbox, But Retaining Classes

Tags: theme-customizer

On a custom theme I had made, I had some options like so:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('swag_header_display_homepage', array(
        'default' => 'header-display-homepage-yes'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('swag_header_display_homepage', array(
        'label' => 'Display Header On Homepage',
        'section' => 'swag_header_display_section',
        'type' => 'select'
        'choices' => array(
            'header-display-homepage-yes' => __('Yes'),
            'header-display-homepage-no' => __('No')
        )
    ));
```

The choices you see there end up being classes that get added to the header.

I tried changing it to a checkbox instead of dropdown selection by changing `'type' => 'select'` to `'type' => 'checkbox'`. Although, I know "choices" are for dropdown selections. How can I keep the classes when changing it to a checkbox.

I tried

```
'std' => array(
            'header-display-homepage-yes' => __('1'),
            'header-display-homepage-no' => __('0')
        )
```

Which I know is wrong on so many levels. How can I do it properly, or is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkboxes would be the incorrect choice for a yes/no option, because you'd be able to select both options. You want *radio* buttons. Just change `type` to `radio`. Radio buttons also support choices, so you won't need to change that part.

Comment: I didn't think it through. Yes, radio would be the better choice, but all this started because I wanted to style it more simply in the customizer. Thanks for pointing that out.